# wanted to write one code for multiple commands in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement element1 = driver.get("http://staging.zingoy.com/");
      WebElement element11 = driver.get("http://staging.zingoy.com/login");

    if (element1!= null && element11!= null ){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/nav/div/div/div[4]/div/span[2]/a[1]")).click();
    System.out.println("LOGin Enter text");
    try{
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
          WebElement element = (WebElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/input")));
          element.click();
          System.out.println("Clicked on the element successfully");
        }catch(Throwable e){
          System.err.println("Error came while waiting for the element and clicking on it. "+e.getMessage());
        }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("mdimertest@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[3]/input")).sendKeys("12345600");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Error type mismatch cannot convert from void to webelement how to solve this

Comment: raw code is nor enough. Please expand your question with details, expose expected result and issues you've met

Answer (score 2):

`driver.get()` returns `void`, you can't assign it to `WebElement` (first two lines).

Answer (score 2):

driver.get("URL") opens the webpage in the specified URL,which is a null.
It cannot be assigned to a WebElement.
Try assigning any element in the page opened in the browser to element1 and check it for null.

Comment: @urban it's answer, not question :P

Comment: @drets: really sorry, must have been too early ... removing